# Javascript passing function by value vs by reference

Tags: javascript

When I do

```
function foo(){//some stuff..}
var bar = foo;
```

I am copying the `foo` to `bar`, right?

Is there a way to assign a function to a variable that will point to a function rather then copy it? so that I may have a few variables assigned the same function, and once this function is updated, all of the assigned variables will be updated too.

I know I can do this with prototype inheritance but I am asking specifically if it is possible with simple variable assigning?

Comment: "I am copying the foo to bar, right?" — Yes, but that **is** a reference.

Comment: how u will update the function ? run time ?

Comment: @Quentin what is the difference then between passing by reference and by value?

Comment: @IlyaD — JavaScript provides no means to create a reference to a variable. You can only assign references to objects (and functions are a type of object). The value of the variable will always be a reference. When you pass that value (of a variable) around you are passing a reference to the function.

Comment: ? http://google.com/?q=what+is+the+difference+then+between+passing+by+reference+and+by+value

Comment: So that means `foo` and `bar` point to a function, and once I assign new value to `foo` it will point to the new value, but `bar` will still be pointing to the initial function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All non-primitive values are passed by reference in JS.

```
function a(val) { a.val = val; }

a(1);

a.val; //1

var b = a;

b(2);

a.val; //2
```

However, if you mean that when you will assign a new reference to a variable, you want all other variables that were referencing the same memory address to be updated so that they reference that new memory address as well, that is not really possible and if you need this feature, you have severe flaws in your design.

Answer (score 0):

foo is not getting copied to bar but foo and bar are referring to the same function object. Your code is similar to this

```
var foo,bar;
foo = bar = function() {};
```

Here foo and bar are reference to same function object. 
Proof:

```
foo.a = "Modified by foo";
alert(bar.a); // echo's "Modified by foo"
```